# System of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

System of differential equations
\begin{cases}
\frac{d^{2}x}{dt^2} + \sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2+ (\frac{dy}{dt})^2}\frac{dy}{dt}=0\\
\frac{d^{2}y}{dt^2} - \sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2+ (\frac{dy}{dt})^2}\frac{dx}{dt}=0
\end{cases}
According to the following image
[image: valid XHTML]
<sub>(source: [uplooder.net](http://www.uplooder.net/img/image/72/e56bd5286f708783559a6c2584bcabc5/Untitled.jpg))</sub>
.

How can i obtain the last answer?
**My attempt:**  putting $X:= \frac{dx}{dt}$ and $Y:=\frac{dy}{dt}$ gives us
\begin{cases}
\frac{dX}{dt} + \sqrt{X^2+ Y^2} Y = 0\\
\frac{dY}{dt} - \sqrt{X^2+ Y^2} X = 0
\end{cases}
then
$$\frac{dX}{dY} - \frac{Y}{X} = 0.$$
Solving the above equation,we have
$$X^2 = Y^2+C$$
that is
$$(\frac{dx}{dt})^2 = (\frac{dy}{dt})^2 +C.$$ I stop here. Is that right?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have a sign error. The conclusion should be $(dx/dt)^2 + (dy/dt)^2 = const.$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the system
\begin{align}
 \frac{\text{d}^2 x}{\text{d} t^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\text{d} y}{\text{d} t} \sqrt{\left(\frac{\text{d} x}{\text{d} t}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\text{d} y}{\text{d} t}\right)^2} &= 0,\\
 \frac{\text{d}^2 y}{\text{d} t^2} - \frac{1}{r}\frac{\text{d} x}{\text{d} t} \sqrt{\left(\frac{\text{d} x}{\text{d} t}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\text{d} y}{\text{d} t}\right)^2} &= 0.\tag{1}
\end{align}
It's worthwhile to note that the 'square root' terms are almost equal: the only difference is that in the first equation, the square root is multiplied by $\frac{\text{d} y}{\text{d} t}$, whereas in the second equation the square root is multiplied by $\frac{\text{d} x}{\text{d} t}$. This suggests the following trick: multiply the first equation by $\frac{\text{d} x}{\text{d} t}$ and the second equation by $\frac{\text{d} y}{\text{d} t}$, and then add them. The square root terms then cancel each other, and you obtain
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\text{d} x}{\text{d} t} \frac{\text{d}^2 x}{\text{d} t^2} +  \frac{\text{d} y}{\text{d} t} \frac{\text{d}^2 y}{\text{d} t^2} = 0.\tag{2}
\end{equation}
Now, we can recognise $\frac{\text{d} x}{\text{d} t} \frac{\text{d}^2 x}{\text{d} t^2}$ as the time derivative of $\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\text{d} x}{\text{d} t} \right)^2$, such that we can rewrite $(2)$ as
\begin{equation}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t}\left[\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\text{d} x}{\text{d} t} \right)^2 + \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\text{d} y}{\text{d} t} \right)^2\right] = 0.\tag{3}
\end{equation}
From $(3)$, we can infer that
\begin{equation}
 \left(\frac{\text{d} x}{\text{d} t}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\text{d} y}{\text{d} t}\right)^2 = \text{constant} = R^2,
\end{equation}
which just means that $\left(\frac{\text{d} x}{\text{d} t},\frac{\text{d} y}{\text{d} t}\right)$ lies on a circle with radius $R$. Therefore, it seems useful to write
\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d} x}{\text{d} t} &= R \,\cos (\theta(t)),\\
\frac{\text{d} y}{\text{d} t} &= R \,\sin (\theta(t)).
\end{align}
If you put this into the system $(1)$, you obtain
\begin{align}
 -R \frac{\text{d} \theta}{\text{d} t} \sin \theta + \frac{R^2}{r} \sin \theta &= 0,\\
R \frac{\text{d} \theta}{\text{d} t} \cos \theta - \frac{R^2}{r} \cos \theta &= 0.
\end{align}
Both equations are equivalent to
\begin{equation}
\frac{\text{d} \theta}{\text{d} t} - \frac{R}{r} = 0,
\end{equation}
which means that
\begin{equation}
 \theta(t) = \frac{R}{r} t + \theta_0.
\end{equation}
I'm sure you can take it from here. Note that you've made a few typos in your question; it's good that you posted an image of the original question.